# Animating width by CSSTransition does not resize adjacent element

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation, react-transition-group

I am trying to animate buttons in such manner that when you click on the button,the next button will be gradually disappearing.The problem is that the button which being clicked does not update its width dynamically,it does so when transitions ends.

Here is [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jvnpljl7z3)

Demo works only when you click on **Decline** button.

How can i make the decline button to update its width while transition occures?
I can not figure it out, thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried setting the flex value from 0 to something small like 0.1?

Also what's with all the !importants?

Comment: Thanks for sharing, i have found  that you can not animate width in this condition.I have did use flex property as you have mentioned.It is a dirty hack though.